# Move two levels higher over SCP

Tags: server, ssh, scp

I am `scp`ing into a virtual server and need to copy some files into the `/var/www/` directory so apache2 can serve 'em up. However, by default, the files that I upload go into the users dirctory. I need to get them two levels up. How would I do this over scp?

Comment: How are you specifying the path at the second part of the `scp` command?

Comment: Like so: ~/var/www

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not specifying `user@host:/var/www` as the destination path you're going to run into this issue.  Note that the user you upload as *MUST* have access to write to the directory.

Assuming that the user has write permissions to `/var/www`, then make sure your scp command follows this general pattern, with `[options]` being replaced by whatever options you need:

`scp [options] /local/path user@remotehost:/remote/path`

Replace the local path and the remote path with the actual paths though.

---

***IF YOU DO NOT WANT TO HAVE THE UPLOAD IN YOUR HOME DIRECTORY, DO NOT USE `~` AT ALL FOR THE BEGINNING OF THE REMOTE PATH!***

`~` is a shortcut to add `/home/$USER` to the path if it appears at the beginning of a path, and is the exact reason you're running into this "Uploading to Home Directory" issue, based on your comment on your question.  Just do `user@host:/var/www` like I specified in my answer here for the remote path.

Comment: I just tried that. It said the following: `scp: /home/ubuntu/var/www: No such file or directory` What should I do now?

Comment: @TJonS, you just pointed out your own problem.  "Like so: `~/var/www` – TJonS 15 mins ago"  <-- that's your comment.  `~` is a shortcut for `/home/$USER`.  Remove the `~ and it'll work.

Comment: @Thomas W. Why do you not recommend the usage of ~ in remote paths? I mean for the question it's obvious, but it sounds like "in GENERAL don't use ~". Because it refers to a variable?

Comment: @Chaos reread the context of the initial question and then all comments and then reread your comments and my answer.  I did not say "In General" don't use.  If you read TJonS comments later, you'll see that he failed and used `~` in the path which led to the whole problem in the first place.  If I had said "Don't use ~ ever!" that would be a different story.  Context of the question and comments and answers is very important here.  To please you, though, I've edited my question, although you need to read up on why context of an answer **in relation to the question** is important.

Comment: @Thomas W. thx for pointing this out. Now it's clear. =)